# Location in web.config of secured pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am developing a Web Applilcation in Asp.net 4.0 , wherein i have two types of Pages "Secured" and "Unsecured".

To access Secure Pages, am using Location tag in my secured's web.config and the user must successfully Login. and after that login am going to copy that url and then logout.

My expected result:-  while am going to paste that url in browser then it will again display me the login page again.

so please give me the example related to my query.

Thanks In Advance.....

Comment: So, what happens? Please explain your problem, the steps to reproduce and the result you expect and the ones you get. Also show the contents of the `<location>` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) tag in your location to restrict access for anonymous users e.g.

```
<location path="Secured.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a folder (perhaps named 'Secure') and add a web.config file inside the folder. It will be very small... possibly as simple as this (which only permits logged-in users):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any page added to the folder will cause a login prompt upon access without the need to do anything else on your part. This is assuming you are using ASP.Net Membership/Security features (as it sounds like from your question).

Note: the additional/small web.config file will be limited to the scope of the folder that contains it.

If you wanted to create a couple roles (we do this for our Internal Admin pages), you can restrict access to only users tied to those roles... it's pretty easy. The following web.config is in our Admin folder that contains all our admin pages...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="FullClearance" />
            <allow roles="HighClearance" /><!-- mgr clearance-->
            <allow roles="StandardClearance" /> <!-- staff clearance-->
            <deny users="*" /><!-- authenticated users -->
            <deny users="?" /><!-- anonymous  users -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```